# What is the memory space of an array in OpenCL kernel?

Tags: arrays, opencl

I wrote an OpenCL kernel function where I declared 
a local array inside the kernel, like:

```
float arr[10000];
```

It seems like now each work item have an independent array of 10000 elements. I am a little confused here since the private registers for
each thread might not be able to hold a 10000-element-array.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenCL spec, § 6.5 Address Space Qualifiers** says:

> The generic address space name for arguments to a function in a program, or local variables of a function is `__private`.

So within a kernel, `float arr[10000]` resides in the private address space. That's all the spec says.

In theory, what happens beyond that point is up to the implementation: it is not specified whether private address space should be physically stored in registers, a register file, some kind of off-chip memory, a combination of those, or something else.

In practice, some implementations will put small arrays in registers depending on a number of factors, while bigger arrays will be put on off-chip memory.

Comment: Somehow it still depends on your underlying hardware. A CPU might hold these elements in its cache, or you might construct a DSP having such a large memory for each processing element. GPUs mostly behave different, as said above.

Comment: Thanks, Cicada. That make sense to me. Is there anyway that you could see the memory usage inside the kernel?